# Formula to get a unique list of values from a column of data where each cell has multiple values delimited by commas

Tags: google-sheets

My raw data is in 1 column. In each row of the column there are multiple values delimited by a comma. I would like a google sheets formula that will create unique list of all these values and I would like the results to be shown in a column (see results table).

The first table is the raw data. Second table is how the results should look

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

| Raw Data |
| --- |
| Catch-Up Q3, GROWTH, H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], H1 2023 [ALL] |
| Catch-Up Q3, H1 2023 [Business need - Regular] |
| CORPO, H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive] |
| CORPO, H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive] |
| CORPO, H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], H1 2023 [ALL] |
| GROWTH, Catch-Up Q3, H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Business need - Regular] |
| GROWTH, CORPO, H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Integration need] |
| GROWTH, H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Business need - Regular] |
| GROWTH, H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], H1 2023 [ALL] |
| GROWTH, H1 2023 [Integration need] |
| H1 2023 [ALL], CORPO, H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive] |
| H1 2023 [ALL], CORPO, H1 2023 [Integration need] |
| H1 2023 [ALL], GROWTH, H1 2023 [Business need - Regular] |
| H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive], CORPO |
| H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive], GROWTH |
| H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], CORPO |
| H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], GROWTH |
| H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], OPS |
| H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], TECH |
| H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Integration need], Catch-Up Q3, GROWTH |
| H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Integration need], CORPO |
| H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Integration need], OPS |
| H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Integration need], PRODUCT |
| H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Integration need], TECH |
| H1 2023 [ALL], OPS, H1 2023 [Business need - Regular] |
| H1 2023 [ALL], OPS, H1 2023 [Integration need] |
| H1 2023 [ALL], PRODUCT |
| H1 2023 [ALL], TECH, H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive] |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive] |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive], CORPO |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive], CORPO, H1 2023 [ALL], OPS |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive], CORPO, OPS, H1 2023 [ALL] |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive], TECH, H1 2023 [ALL] |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Regular] |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], Catch-Up Q3 |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], GROWTH, H1 2023 [ALL] |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], H1 2023 [ALL], CORPO, H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive] |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], H1 2023 [ALL], GROWTH |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], H1 2023 [ALL], OPS |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], H1 2023 [ALL], PRODUCT |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], H1 2023 [ALL], TECH |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], OPS, Catch-Up Q3 |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], OPS, H1 2023 [ALL] |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], TECH, H1 2023 [ALL] |
| H1 2023 [Integration need] |
| H1 2023 [Integration need], H1 2023 [ALL], OPS |
| H1 2023 [Integration need], TECH |
| H1 2023 [Integration need], TECH, H1 2023 [ALL] |
| OPS, H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive] |
| OPS, H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Integration need] |
| OPS, H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive] |
| OPS, H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive], H1 2023 [ALL] |
| OPS, H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], H1 2023 [ALL] |
| OPS, H1 2023 [Integration need], H1 2023 [ALL] |
| PRODUCT, H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Business need - Regular] |
| PRODUCT, H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Integration need] |
| PRODUCT, H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive] |
| PRODUCT, H1 2023 [Business need - Regular] |
| PRODUCT, H1 2023 [Integration need], H1 2023 [ALL] |
| TECH, H1 2023 [ALL], Catch-Up Q3, H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive] |
| TECH, H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Business need - Regular] |
| TECH, H1 2023 [ALL], H1 2023 [Integration need] |
| TECH, H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive], H1 2023 [ALL] |
| TECH, H1 2023 [Business need - Regular], H1 2023 [ALL] |
| TECH, H1 2023 [Integration need] |

| Results |
| --- |
| Catch-Up Q3 |
| CORPO |
| GROWTH |
| H1 2023 [ALL] |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Intensive] |
| H1 2023 [Business need - Regular] |
| H1 2023 [Integration need] |
| OPS |
| PRODUCT |
| TECH |

Comment: Try if using `Excel` --> `=UNIQUE(DROP(REDUCE("",B4:B68,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TEXTSPLIT(TRIM(y),,", ",1)))),1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try if using `Excel`:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C4`

```
=VSTACK("Results",SORT(UNIQUE(DROP(REDUCE("",B4:B68,
LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TEXTSPLIT(TRIM(y),,", ",1)))),1))))
```

---

In `Google-Sheets` you could try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C3`

```
=LET(x,VSTACK("Results",SORT(UNIQUE(REDUCE("",B4:B68,
LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,FLATTEN(SPLIT(TRIM(y),", ",,1)))))))),FILTER(x,x<>""))
```

---

So i have tired another way found this one also works:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E3`

```
=VSTACK("Results",SORT(UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(SPLIT(B4:B68,", ",,1))))))
```

---

Comment: thank you but I'm using google sheets. apoligies for the confusion. I have just edited the question to specify this.

Comment: @fini-stair for `Google-Sheets` try this : `=UNIQUE(REDUCE("",B4:B68,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,FLATTEN(SPLIT(y,", ",,1))))))`